# Connect to Cisco VPN using Shrew

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco

I'm using Vista 64 and could not set up the Cisco 32 bit VPN client. I saw in one of the posts that you could use Shrew instead. I need some guidance on setting up Shrew to connect to my office network.
I know the IP and group authentication details but do not have a pcf file or a security certificate

Answer (score 1):

If you need the pcf file. Get a machine that has the same connection group policy as you, and has the 32 bit cisco client installed, and grab the .pcf file off that machine. It's normally in the program files\cisco systems\vpnclient\profiles directory. Maybe you can get what you need from there.

I'm not familiar with Shrew but deploying the cisco client here i just copy the .pcf file into that directory and then give the user their login/password.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend getting away from the "old school" vpn client and pcf's and use the AnyConnect client.  The password hashed password embedded in the pcf is easily cracked.  Are you connecting to an ASA?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't know that the Cisco client will not run under 64 bit and that Cisco is planning to discontinue it.  The AnyConnect client is cool **IF YOU ARE NOT USING IPSEC**. AnyConnect will NOT connect to it. Nor will any future Cisco products. Because they are the number 1 supplier of hardware and has the largest base of IPSEC hardware, they want eeryone to move to their new platform and buy new stuff. In our group we estimate that it will cost between **eight and ten MILLION DOLLARS** to change out the hardware. Are we? No. Are we buying any more Cisco hardware......**NO**